# Maintenance plan delete backup

Tags: sql-server-2008

I succeeded in making a backup through maintenance plan.

All I need now is to find how to delete a folder (containing old backup) through the same maintenance plan.

Answer (score 3):

Bob,

I am NOT a big fan of maintenance plans and I try to avoid using them. While they work ok for small needs it becomes hard to customize them but some ppl disagree with that.

You need to look at the Maintenance Plan cleanup task. Make sure you enter the extension as 'bak' without quotes instead of '.bak' without quotes. The following two articles will help for you. Let us know if you need further help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177182.aspx

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BradSchacht/ssis/249/sql-maintenance-plan-doesn-t-delete-backups

Comment: In the absence of "real" DBAs (no disrespect to OP intended) Maintenance Plans are a relatively painless way of doing backups, stats and index maintenance. I don't use/like them either but they are still useful.

Comment: Gbn, Unless you can hop onto SSIS and tweak some aspects, MP are known to do some dumb things. For relatively low workloads it may be fine but on mi-larger systems its totally waste of resources.

Comment: One would hope there is a DBA for a larger system, no?

Comment: Gbn, That is wishful thinking (YMMV) in this economy but looks like we have had different experiences so far.

Comment: Okay DBAs, inform a developer stuck with the hat of DBA - what alternative to Maintenance Plans do the real DBAs prefer?  SQL Scripts?  3rd-part software?  Maybe you should answer as a full-blown answer, so other DBAs can upvote.